# Heroku nginx websockets

Tags: node.js, nginx, heroku, websocket, reverse-proxy

I've been trying to get websockets to work on heroku over nginx and seem to be stuck.  I'm using the [nginx-buildpack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) which has worked great but I haven't had any success thus far getting an upgraded websocket connection.

Here is my nginx.conf.erb, which is just slightly modified from the buildpack example...

```
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have 4 cores.
worker_processes 4;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;

    log_format l2met 'measure.nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_heroku_request_id';
    access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
    error_log logs/nginx/error.log;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    #Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;
    proxy_read_timeout 950s;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location /test {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

To test this configuration< i've just been using the websocket.org [Echo Test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html).  Unfortunately it is not able to connect.

On port 3001 I've just got a simple socket.io server, and I'm logging any connections (none so far...)...

```
var app2 = require('http').createServer().listen(3001);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app2);

io.on('connection', function(socketconnection){
    socketconnection.send("Connected to Server-1");
    console.log("connected to websocket server!");
    socketconnection.on('message', function(message){
        socketconnection.send(message);
    });
});
```

When I try connecting with the websockets tester this is the error that I get in my heroku logs...

*3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response
   header from upstream, client: 10.140.231.210, server: _, request: "GET /?         encoding=text HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/?encoding=t
 ext", host: "www.mydomain.com"

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong here?

***UPDATE 1*** : 
Ok, I so I've found that if I alter the section of my config where it is says :

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}
```

to:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
}
```

this seems to prevent that error from occurring.  I suppose this is due to a blank response being returned on connect.  However, now that I've done this I get a new error:

```
*5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 10.99.212.2, server: _, request: "GET /?encoding=text HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/?encoding=text", host: "www.mydomain.com"
```

I suppose this may be an issue unrelated to the first, but I'm not sure!

Comment: You do not appear to be using `$connection_upgrade`. From [this link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) you should probably be using `proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to make a difference, I still get the 111: Connection refused.

Comment: ok, so it seems as though it is related to my use of socket.io... if I use just ws as is used in the nginx example, it is not an issue.... why that is I still cannot figure out...

Comment: another thing that I had done to get it working, which I assumed was equivalent but perhaps not is move the proxy_pass location into an upstream tag... I've reverted that and confirmed that without that it does nto work...